# Amazon EC2 latency

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, latency

What's the expected latency for a simple connection between a pair of Amazon EC2 instances in the same region?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The latency should be similar to the latency of two computers in the same LAN. Just make sure that you are using the private IPs when connecting the two images and not their public ones.

Comment: What's this latency? 1 millisecond? 10 milliseconds? 100 milliseconds?

Comment: It should be in the range of 1 millisecond. Why don't you make an experiment? Start two instances and make a ping from one to another.

Comment: I get an average latency of 1 millisecond for all users coming into my load balancers externally across all instances. Given this I would think internally it'll be very very fast.