# Determine Request Latency

Tags: amazon-ec2, go, latency

I'm working on creating a version of Pastry natively in Go. From the [design](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/antr/PAST/pastry.pdf) [PDF]:

> It is assumed that the application
>   provides a function that allows each Pastry node to determine the “distance” of a node
>   with a given IP address to itself. A node with a lower distance value is assumed to be
>   more desirable. An application is expected to implements this function depending on its
>   choice of a proximity metric, using network services like traceroute or Internet subnet
>   maps, and appropriate caching and approximation techniques to minimize overhead.

I'm trying to figure out what the best way to determine the "proximity" (i.e., network latency) between two EC2 instances programmatically from Go. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with low-level networking to be able to differentiate between the different types of requests I could use. Googling did not turn up any suggestions for measuring latency from Go, and general latency techniques always seem to be Linux binaries, which I'm hoping to avoid in the name of fewer dependencies. Any help?

Also, I [note](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490168/amazon-ec2-latency) that the latency should be on the scale of 1ms between two EC2 instances. While I plan to use the implementation on EC2, it could hypothetically be used anywhere. Is latency generally so bad that I should expend the effort to ensure the network proximity of two nodes? Keep in mind that most Pastry requests can be served in log base 16 of the number of servers in the cluster (so for 10,000 servers, it would take approximately 3 requests, on average, to find the key being searched for). Is the latency from, for example, EC2's Asia-Pacific region to EC2's US-East region enough to justify the increased complexity and the overhead introduced by the latency checks when adding nodes?

Comment: It's impossible to answer the questions about if this is necessary/worthwhile without knowing your goals. Do you have a specific latency target? Are you trying to minimize bandwidth costs of communicating between EC2 regions?

Comment: I'm trying to make an intelligent tradeoff between communication delays and bandwidth use. No latency target beyond "reasonable". This is complicated by the fact that I want to release this as a general purpose package, so it can't be EC2 specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common distance metric in networking is to **count the number of hops** (node-hops in-between) a packet needs to reach its destination. This metric was also mentioned in the text you quoted. This could give you adequate distance values even for the low-latency environment you mentioned (EC2 “local”).

For the go logic itself, one would think the **[`net`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#Dial) package** is what you are looking for. And indeed, **for latency tests (ICMP ping)** you could use it to create an IP connection

```
conn, err := net.Dial("ip4", "127.0.0.1")
```

create your **ICMP package** structure and data, and send it. (See [Wikipedia page on ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#ICMP_segment_structure); IPv6 needs a different format.) Unfortunately you can’t create an ICMP connection directly, like you can with TCP and UDP, thus you will have to handle the package structure yourself.

As `conn` of type [`Conn`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#Conn) is a `Writer`, you can then pass it your data, the ICMP data you defined.

In the **ICMP Type** field you can specify the message type. Values 8, 1 and 30 are the ones you are looking for. 8 for your echo request, the reply will be of type 1. And maybe 30 gives you some more information.

Unfortunately, for **counting the network hops**, you will need the IP packet header fields. This means, you will have to **construct your own IP packets**, which `net` does not seem to allow.

Checking the [source of `Dial()`](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/dial.go?s=2299:2340#L81), it uses `internetSocket`, which is not exported/public. I’m not really sure if I’m missing something, but it seems there is no simple way to construct your own IP packets to send, with customizable header values. You’d have to further check how `DialIP` sends packages with `internetSocket` and duplicate and adapt that code/concept. Alternatively, you could use cgo and a system library to construct your own packages (this would add yet more complexity though).

If you are planning on using **[IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_packet#Fixed_header)**, you will (also) have to look into [ICMPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICMPv6). Both packages have a different structure over their v4 versions.

---

So, I’d suggest using simple latency (timed ping) as a simple(r) implementation and then add node-hops at a later time/afterwards, if you need it. If you have both in place, maybe you also want to combine those 2 (less hops does not automatically mean better; think long overseas-cables etc).

Comment: @ElazarLeibovich can you expand on that?

Comment: @PaddyForan call `syscall.Socket(syscall.AF_INET, syscall.SOCK_RAW, port)`, then you should be able to construct ICMP packets yourself.